# SQL How to group the rows correctly

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have three tables:

```
**Bookie**:

------------

Id : int (Primary Key)

Bookie : varchar
```

---

```
**Transactions**:

-------------------

Id : int (Primary Key)

Date : date

Bookie : int (Foreign Key)

Amount : decimal
```

---

```
Wagers:

Id : int (Primary Key)

Stake : decimal

Bookie : int (Foreign Key)
```

Wagers table is not entire but for the sql these columns are sufficient.

I tried this sql code so far:

```
SELECT Bookie.Bookie, SUM(Amount), Wagers.Stake FROM Transactions
JOIN Bookie on Transactions.Bookie = Bookie.Id
JOIN Wagers on Bookie.Id = Wagers.Bookie
GROUP BY Bookie.Bookie, Wagers.Stake
```

But my output looks like this:

```
Bookie | Amount | Stake
William Hill | 600.00 | 14.70
Bet at Home | 500.00 | 30.00
Bet at Home | 500.00 | 45.00
Bet at Home | 500.00 | 50.00
Bet365 | 10200.00 | 100.00
```

It should look like this:

```
Bookie | Amount | Stake
William Hill | 600.00 | 14.70
Bet at Home | 500.00 | 125.00
Bet365 | 10200.00 | 100.00
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: instead of `Wagers.Stake` do `sum(Wagers.Stake) as Stake` and remove `group by Stake`

Comment: @Gohan Which database you are using?

Comment: I don't get it, but I can see others do, so I'll leave it to them.

Comment: @J19 i am using MSSQL within the SQL Server Management Studio...

Abhik Chakraborty please take a look on the comment under that answer from lad2025

Comment: It is strange you chose to group by Bookie.Bookie and Wagers.Stake in the first place, because this means you want one result row per bookie and stake, where you obviously only want one result row per bookie.

Comment: Yeah, this was because of the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio error where it's says that the column must be an aggregat or in the GROUP BY clause. And i really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate `Stake`:

```
SELECT Bookie.Bookie, SUM(Amount) AS Amount, SUM(Wagers.Stake) AS Stake
FROM Transactions
JOIN Bookie 
  ON Transactions.Bookie = Bookie.Id
JOIN Wagers 
  ON Bookie.Id = Wagers.Bookie
GROUP BY Bookie.Bookie;
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT Bookie, MAX(Amount) AS Amount, SUM(Stake) AS Stake
FROM (
  SELECT Bookie.Bookie, SUM(Amount) AS Amount, Wagers.Stake 
  FROM Transactions
  JOIN Bookie on Transactions.Bookie = Bookie.Id
  JOIN Wagers on Bookie.Id = Wagers.Bookie
  GROUP BY Bookie.Bookie, Wagers.Stake
) AS sub
GROUP BY Bookie;
```

Comment: That is what I already tried to do, but i won't work.

The output looks then like this:

William Hill | 600.00 | 29.40 // 14.70 (Stake) would be correct
Bet at Home | 1500.00 | 125.00 // 500.00 (Amount) would be correct
Bet365 | 10200.00 | 200.00 // 100.00 (Stake) would be correct

Comment: Thank you now all is perfect :)

Comment: That's a rather obfuscated way to get this done, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

With aggregates from two different tables it is best to pre-aggregate the data and only then join:

```
select 
  b.bookie, 
  t.sum_amount, 
  w.sum_stake
from bookie b 
join
(
  select bookie, sum(amount) as sum_amount
  from transactions
  group by bookie
) t on t.bookie = b.id
join       
(
  select bookie, sum(stake) as sum_stake
  from wagers 
  group by bookie
) w on w.bookie = b.id;
```

As you are only interested in one aggregation from each table, you can even use correlated subqueries in the select clause instead. Easy to write and easy to read :-)

```
select 
  b.bookie, 
  (select sum(t.amount) from transactions t where t.bookie = b.id),
  (select sum(w.stake) from wagers w where w.bookie = b.id)
from bookie b
```

Comment: Thank you, first works fine

second does not work because of a syntax near 'from' or b.bookie multi-part identifier was not found after the select clause

Comment: Ah, there was a comma missing. I've added it.

Comment: Thank you, I missed it. Your answer is correct too but the other person posted earlier, that's why I mark his answer as correct...although i use your second solution, because of it's shortness.

Comment: No Problem :-) Just an advice: Though lad2025 gets to the correct result and their query is not bad, it is the patterns I'm showing you should keep in mind :-) As mentioned: if you are only interested in one value, you can get it in a subselect, otherwise join the aggregated data. You see that in both cases there is no group by in the main query, so you don't run the risk of mistakenly aggregating values multifold. It's simply a good pattern to apply when it comes to aggregation.